# Trimming Draft.js Editor content with the OnBlur event

Tags: reactjs, mouseevent, trim, onblur, draftjs

In order to trim the content of the Draft.js Editor, the following answer works with the `onClick` event: [Draft.js - How to trim contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46802855/draft-js-how-to-trim-contents)

However, I'm unable to make it work with the `onBlur` event.

In both cases it reaches the method, but only when clicking on the button it performs a trimming of the content.

You can reproduce this problem in the following JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pnfgrhqz/1/

If you add spaces at the beginning and then click the button, it will trim the content, however, if you do the same and then click out of focus, the `trimContent` method is also triggered, but the content will not be trimmed.

Any idea what am I missing here?

Comment: your code works for me in Firefox & Safari. Also when I switch focus

Comment: That's surprising, I've checked now both Firefox and Safari and in my case it does not trim the spaces when switching focus. I don't really understand how it's possible that the JS Fiddle does work in your case.

Comment: Ohh i see you want to have it when you blur the editor ? i missed that point ... let me try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options. you can either call the trimmer with a setTimeout

```
  trimOnBlur = () =>{setTimeout(this.trimContent , 0);}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bsv3oegr/1/

or add the onBlur event on the parent div and make it focusable with tabIndex.

```
 tabIndex="0" onBlur={this.trimContent}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8rtcgqkb/

Comment: Not sure which one of the two solutions it's better, but both worked for me, thanks!

Comment: the first one should be fine for your case.. just keep the tabIndex in mind if you deal with atomic blocks.. super helpful if you need focus actions.